# before_filter not being called rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a custom method outside the generic CRUD in my friendships controller called request. My problem is that I have `before_filter :require_auth` set to run before all methods in my `FriendshipsController`.

It was working fine except for the request method.

(This makes me think it has something to do with it being out of normal CRUD?)

When I call the request method now it skips the `:require_auth` and goes straight to the request method which is giving me errors as I define some variables in `:require_auth` that I need inside the request method.

Here is my `FriendshipsController`:

```
class FriendshipsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:create]

  before_filter :require_auth

  def create
    @friendship = Friendship.new(user_id: params[:user_id], friend_id: params[:friend_id], status: params[:status])

    if @friendship.save
      render :status => 200, :json => {:message => "Friendship Created"}
    else
      render :status => 500, :json => { :message => "Problem creating friendship" }
    end
  end

  def request
    # friendID = params[:friend_id]
    # userID = @currentuser.id
    binding.pry
    @userid = @currentuser.id
    @friendid = params[:friend_id]
    unless (@userid == @friendid || Friendship.exists?(user_id: @userid,friend_id: @friendid))
      create(:user_id => userID, :friend_id => friendID, :status => 'pending')
      create(:user_id => friendID, :friend_id => userID, :status => 'requested')
    end
  end

end
```

Here is my `ApplicationController` where I define `require_auth`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  # protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def require_auth
    binding.pry
    auth_token = request.headers["HTTP_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    @user = User.find_by_auth_token(auth_token)
    if @user.auth_token
      @currentuser = @user
    else
      render :status => 401, :json => {:error => "Requires authorization"}
      return false
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: What Rails version? Cause in Rails 4 it calls `before_action`. However it should be another error.

Comment: @zishe I believe `before_filter` still works in Rails 4 but is deprecated.

Comment: Consider changing the name of your action. `request` is normally the name of an object that you can call to obtain information about the current request.

Comment: request is already defined in rails as per @ChrisPeters http://rails.nuvvo.com/lesson/6377-action-controller-the-request-and-response-objects

Answer (score 1):

Chris Peters was right in the comments. My problem was that rails already has request defined. I simple changed the method name to something else and it works.

Thanks.